# Pre-fill SVN commit message with guideline

Tags: svn, hook

I would like to show guidelines to commiter independently of the subversion client used.
Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is possible. Suppose I do

```
svn ci somefile -m "my commit message"
```

from the command line. You could certainly install a hook on your SVN server to
detect and reject commits with messages that don't conform to your standard, but 
actually pre-filling the commit message for arbitrary clients won't work, because
the commit message can be supplied before the client ever contacts the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To my mind my request is an interesting feature which could permit to educate developers.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, you want clients that prompt the user for a commit message to prefill the text area/file with a custom message. If so, subversion doesn't support that through any kind of repository configuration